# Google Apps Script (Web Apps): Can I use query strings?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, export-to-csv

I had this idea to create an Apps Script app that I could pass a Google Drive spreadsheet name and have it return .CSV output. So, basically a CSV exporter.

I feel like I should be able to do something like this:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykY80bhm_ZwbY1-zXY37JJLD8zToZuxup8-eXovJQ/exec?filename=sheet-i-want-to-export-to-csv

And then receive raw .CSV data as a result.

Is this possible? If so, how?

It seems like Web Apps doesn't allow query strings, at least not via the usual ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() method.

Comment: It is possible to receive url parameters in a Apps Script web-app, it's in the first (and only) parameter passed to your `doGet` function. And you can use the `ContentService` to return the CSV. It is somewhat straightforward to implement. But Google drive has this as a built-in functionality, like shown in Lenny's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the "key" and the "sheet" or it's id #

"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+"&exportFormat=csv&gid="+sheet+"&gridlines=0&printtitle=0&size=7&fzr=true&portrait=1&fitw=1"

Comment: This is the correct answer; however, as written it sends you through a 302 Moved Temporarily.

Comment: Make sure no " are in there.  The key and sheet number should follow immediately after the =